# Is it possible to harden aes encryption against brute force attack?

Tags: security, encryption, aes, password-protection, brute-force

is there any way to harden aes encryption against brute force attack without strengthening password. I mean users generally choose easy passwords. I don't want to force users to choose more and more complicated password.(This is the correct solution but it is useless when they forget their passwords continuously, and they cannot use their password) They choose their passwords from uppercase, lowercase and digits. And password length is 8. I want to make it difficult to brute force attacking without changing these password properties.

EDIT: Password length is exactly 8. Less length is not acceptable. And one more question over replies, keeping encrypted text on memory (using salting and key stretching) is a security problem?

Comment: That's the second off topic question out of two Mehmet.

Answer (score 3):

I'm tempted to say that: *No, it is not possible.* In order to make the brute force attack harder, you need more entropy.

That being said, you can actually make the guessing process slower if you do [key stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching).

Comment: So what about storing encrypted text in memory, is it a security problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to comment on the problem without knowing the exact nature of how it's being used. (For e.g., can the password only be stored as 8 characters?).

That said, choosing a good [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) makes brute forcing harder. Most passwords stolen today are the result of failure to implement proper salting.

For more security you can employ [consistent hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) to shard the salt over a range of values.

Comment: ... or individually allocated salts for each entry instead of one for the full database of passwords.

Comment: @Rik: exactly, the bast salt is a *globally unique* salt, 128 bits is your lower margin.

Comment: @HubertKario If it's an individually allocated salt for each entry, then storage of the salts become a problem. Which is why I recommended consistent hashing to distribute the salt over a range. For a sufficient number of passwords, (of the order of 2^(n - 1)), the salt will highly likely be unique.

Comment: Your answer isn't clear on what you hash to get the salt. I also don't see why consistent hashing is useful here.

Comment: @Asti: if storage of 16 bytes of information is a problem, then you've got much bigger issues to work out... Remember: premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to secure your users against using passwords like "password", "12345678" or similar, then **no** there's no way to harden them.

You must be able to check if provided password matches the hash you have in reasonable time (that is, less than 1s on average hardware). Brute forcing simple passwords even when checking equality between hash and password takes 1s will take less than a day on an average PC.

If you want to secure average quality passwords (not in the top 1000 most common passwords or single words from few most commonly spoken languages), then password/key stretching is your best bet: scrypt, bcrypt or the standard PBKDF2 are good choices.

Comment: Salt(unique per user) together with key stretching is the way to go.

Comment: Correct salting and stretching hardens even simple passwords like "password". (If it is the first password guessed, then yes, that's going to fail, but it still dramatically helps against brute force as requested.)

Comment: @RobNapier: how is changing attack time on most common passwords from 5 minutes to 10 hours going to help you?

Comment: First, for the same reason that a TRTL-30 safe is better than a TL-15 safe. Security is practiced against real attackers with finite resources and their own cost/benefit analysis. Making their job harder is a win. More generally, salting, stretching, and a random IV protect against rainbow table-style attacks. Don't assume the only attack is "take one message, crack it." Many attacks look like "take many messages, see if any of them look like something I know." Salting makes that hard. For completeness on attacks: http://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: @RobNapier: I'm not dismissing salting and stretching, in fact I consider any password storage not using them to be broken from the start. I'm only pointing out that it does not help in protecting *very* weak passwords, no matter the kind of attack.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple rounds will slow down the process of trying out passwords but thats about all I can think of.